# Python: Why do i need to use pd.Timestamp. and datetime.datetime. to find difference in days between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

I'm trying to find the difference in two dates (today and dataframe cell) and if the difference is > than 2years I need to remove the relevant row from the dataframe.
I'm sure there is a better way than the one I have put together (it has taken me a few days to get this far).  I found a way that seems to work ok by using pd.Timestamp. and datetime.datetime.

My code is:

```
# why do i need to use pd.Timestamp. and datetime.datetime.  ?
sd2 = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%d-%b-%y')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(sd2, "%d-%b-%y")

# get data from xlsx file
path = (r"C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\PythonSand\PY_Scripts\CleanModules\Racecards")
hist_file = "\RC_jkyhist_NaN.xlsx"
racecard_path = path + hist_file
df_hist = pd.read_excel(racecard_path)
df_hist = df_hist.dropna()          # Remove rows with NaN NaT
df_hist = df_hist.reset_index(drop=True) #clear index ready iterating

# remove all rows where the date is older than 2years, 365 x 2 = 730 days
# first replace the cell with NaT if date delta > 730
cnt = -1  # loc counter
for i in df_hist['RaceDate']:
    cnt = cnt + 1
    date_str = df_hist.loc[cnt, 'RaceDate']
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%b-%y")
    delta =  abs((d2 - d1).days)
    
    if delta > 730: 
        df_hist.loc[cnt, 'RaceDate'] = pd.NaT
    else:
        df_hist.loc[cnt, 'RaceDate'] = df_hist.loc[cnt, 'RaceDate']
    
df_hist = df_hist.dropna()          # Remove rows with NaN NaT
df_hist = df_hist.reset_index(drop=True) #clear index ready for merging
print(df_hist)
```

A sample of the xlsx file is (sorry I am not sure how to insert the table properly):

```
    Jockey  Code    Course  RaceDate    Ran FPos    TotalBtn
Harry Burns AW  Chelmsford City 01-Sep-18   9   4   4.5
Harry Burns AW  Newcastle   01-Oct-21   14  6   4.75
Harry Burns AW  Kempton 01-Nov-21   11  4   4.25
Harry Burns AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   12  4   3.75
Harry Burns AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   12  5   4.75
Christian Howarth   AW  Kempton 01-Dec-21   14  5   3.5
Harry Davies    AW                  
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Dec-17   14  9   10.5
Jonathan Fisher AW  Chelmsford City 01-Dec-17   10  8   4.82
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   12  5   7.75
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   14  4   3
Jonathan Fisher AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   7   4   2
Jonathan Fisher AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   11  8   3
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your data is datetime, and you want to do arithmetic on datetime, then yes, either of them supports subtraction and comparison. My question would be why not just `pd.Timestamp` and `pd.Timedelta`? Pandas supports vectorized operations on the whole series, **AVOID** `for` loop if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Quang.  I'm a newbie to python so I tried lots of things to get to where I am but I don't know how to what you mean by "why not just pd.Timestamp and pd.Timedelta? "

Comment: @QuangHoang  Hi Quang.  So, I tried the following code (I assume this is the vectorized operation) but keep getting errors.     

    d2 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
    df_hist['RaceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_hist['RaceDate'])   

    if  df_hist.loc[df_hist['RaceDate']] - d2 > 730:
        df_hist.loc[df_hist['RaceDate']] = ""

Answer (score 0):

With some input from @enke on this post - [Python: remove all rows from a dataframe where the date is over 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070833/python-remove-all-rows-from-a-dataframe-where-the-date-is-over-2-years-ago)

Final code becomes:

```
import pandas as pd import datetime
# get data from xlsx file
path = (r"C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\PythonSand\PY_Scripts\CleanModules\Racecards")
hist_file = "\RC_jkyhist_NaN.xlsx"
racecard_path = path + hist_file
df_hist = pd.read_excel(racecard_path)
df_hist = df_hist.dropna()          # Remove rows with NaN NaT

date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
df_hist['RaceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_hist['RaceDate'])   

msk = df_hist['RaceDate'].rsub(pd.to_datetime(date_now)).astype('timedelta64[Y]') < 2

new_df = df_hist[msk]
```