# Python: remove all rows from a dataframe where the date is over 2 years ago

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

EDIT - Answer as below with the extra code `new_df = df_hist[msk]`

I'm trying to remove all rows from a DataFrame where the date ('RaceDate') is over 2 years ago. I convert the 'RaceDate' using `pd.to_datetime` - this gives the format e.g. `2018-09-01`. I use `datetime.datetime.now().date()` and this gives the format `datetime.date(2022, 2, 10)`

I can't work out how to check the difference is over two years as the code gives me Key error.
Any help would be most welcome.

```
d2 = datetime.datetime.now().date()
df_hist['RaceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_hist['RaceDate'])   

if  df_hist.loc[df_hist['RaceDate']] - d2 > 730:
    df_hist.loc[df_hist['RaceDate']] = ""
```

Sample data:

```
Jockey  Code    Course  RaceDate    Ran FPos    TotalBtn
Harry Burns AW  Chelmsford City 01-Sep-18   9   4   4.5
Harry Burns AW  Newcastle   01-Oct-21   14  6   4.75
Harry Burns AW  Kempton 01-Nov-21   11  4   4.25
Harry Burns AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   12  4   3.75
Harry Burns AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   12  5   4.75
Christian Howarth   AW  Kempton 01-Dec-21   14  5   3.5
Harry Davies    AW                  
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Dec-17   14  9   10.5
Jonathan Fisher AW  Chelmsford City 01-Dec-17   10  8   4.82
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   12  5   7.75
Jonathan Fisher AW  Southwell   01-Jan-22   14  4   3
Jonathan Fisher AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   7   4   2
Jonathan Fisher AW  Wolverhampton   01-Feb-22   11  8   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `d2` using `pd.to_datetime` and subtract (since today's date is greater than yesterday's date, we subtract today's date from the column using `rsub`). Then convert the timedelta to year and evaluate if the time difference in years is less than 2:

```
msk = df_hist['RaceDate'].rsub(pd.to_datetime(d2)).astype('timedelta64[Y]') < 2
races_dates_in_last_2_years = df_hist.loc[msk, 'RaceDate']
```

or if you wish you filter the entire DataFrame:

```
new_df = df_hist[msk]
```

For example:

For the below Series:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2020-02-10', '2020-02-11']))
```

that looks like:

```
0   2020-02-10
1   2020-02-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

the above code produces:

```
0   2020-02-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```